# Error creating FlipView control in Windows Phone 8 SDK

Tags: windows-phone-8

When i create control As [FlipView control is not available in Windows Phone 8 SDK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15897948/flipview-control-is-not-available-in-windows-phone-8-sdk)
i get the following error

**Error 1** Xap packaging failed. Cannot access a closed Stream.
**Error 2** The type `FlipViewControl:FlipView` was not found. Verify that you are not missing an assembly reference and that all referenced assemblies have been built.
**Error 3** The attachable property 'ItemTemplate' was not found in type `FlipView`.

Here is code:

```
<Grid x:Name="FlipImage" Grid.Row="1">
  <FlipViewControl:FlipView Name="imgViewer">
    <FlipViewControl:FlipView.ItemTemplate>
      <DataTemplate>
        <Image Source="{Binding}" Stretch="Fill"/>
      </DataTemplate>
    </FlipViewControl:FlipView.ItemTemplate>
  </FlipViewControl:FlipView>
</Grid>
```

In Header `xmlns:FlipViewControl="clr-namespace:TruyenMoi"`
I have a error Error 1 Xap packaging failed. Cannot access a closed Stream. I don't understand it.

Comment: What control do you mean? can you provide us some code?

Comment: <Grid x:Name="FlipImage" Grid.Row="1"><FlipViewControl:FlipView Name="imgViewer"><FlipViewControl:FlipView.ItemTemplate><DataTemplate><Image Source="{Binding}" Stretch="Fill"/></DataTemplate></FlipViewControl:FlipView.ItemTemplate>
</FlipViewControl:FlipView></Grid>. In Header  xmlns:FlipViewControl="clr-namespace:TruyenMoi"

Comment: I have a error Error 1 Xap packaging failed. Cannot access a closed Stream. I don't understand it ?

Comment: is `clr-namespace:TruyenMoi` in your project?

Comment: my project name is TruyenMoi

Comment: Ok, and is there FlipViewControl class?

Comment: Uh. My control is FlipView. But this error is Error 1 Xap packaging failed. Cannot access a closed Stream.